# Navigation using google map version2 in Android?

Tags: audit, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am new to this `google map` Activity facing some issue.
How to Navigate on the path drawn from source to destination in android using google map Version 2.

I am able to draw the path from Source to destination using lat & long.
now if the user moves from source to destination than an icon should move on the path drawn.

It would be helpful if you guys give any link or sample.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking out the 2013 Google I/O session "When Android Meets Maps":
https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325172829

They show a demo of some first-person perspective camera control given a path that's returned from the [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/).  This is essentially what you would do in a real-time navigation app, but you would base the camera position on the user's real-time location.

The source-code for the demos shown in that session are on Github:
https://github.com/googlemaps/hellomap-android/wiki